# How To Hide Div Padding Until Visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you goto http://jsfiddle.net/BT4Bk/ you can see that the dark bar is visible.

This is padding for the #ajax div that will wrap the content inside.  How do I hide the padding so its not displayed until it slides into view with the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide your `#dark` until the link is clicked. I added `#dark { display: none; }` to the CSS and `$('#dark').show()` to your animate function:

http://jsfiddle.net/tU3jr/

This jsFiddle will prevent the black padding from shown before the animation runs.

Answer (score 1):

Once you click on the Item 1 padding-top is updated.Look into the following updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/BT4Bk/3/

Comment: The black padding (only) is visible for a second like this. Presumably, that's undesirable. I fixed it in my answer by not showing the `#dark` div until the animate function executes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the

```
#ajax{
    padding: 0px 0; // padding value from here
}
```

Same to added `$(".viewproject").click(function ()`

```
$('#ajax').css("padding-top",40);
```

So all time padding is not taken when you request the item required padding set using jQuery. 
Here @Kiran done is absolutely correct.